# Token creation and crowdsale

Tags: crowdsale, rinkeby, error

I'm trying to create a token and a crowdsale on Rinkeby I managed to create both but when I want to send ethereum to the crowdsale I get an error:

> if you submit it may consume all the gas you provided

I looked on the forum and the solution was to put the function payable but it already is, so I'm little confuse what I should edit

the token code I used:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.16;

contract owned {
    address public owner;

    function owned() public {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    modifier onlyOwner {
        require(msg.sender == owner);
        _;
    }

    function transferOwnership(address newOwner) onlyOwner public {
        owner = newOwner;
    }
}

interface tokenRecipient { function receiveApproval(address _from, uint256 _value, address _token, bytes _extraData) public; }

contract TokenERC20 {
    // Public variables of the token
    string public name;
    string public symbol;
    uint8 public decimals = 18;
    // 18 decimals is the strongly suggested default, avoid changing it
    uint256 public totalSupply;

    // This creates an array with all balances
    mapping (address => uint256) public balanceOf;
    mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) public allowance;

    // This generates a public event on the blockchain that will notify clients
    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);

    // This notifies clients about the amount burnt
    event Burn(address indexed from, uint256 value);

    /**
     * Constrctor function
     *
     * Initializes contract with initial supply tokens to the creator of the contract
     */
    function TokenERC20(
        uint256 initialSupply,
        string tokenName,
        string tokenSymbol
    ) public {
        totalSupply = initialSupply * 10 ** uint256(decimals);  // Update total supply with the decimal amount
        balanceOf[msg.sender] = totalSupply;                // Give the creator all initial tokens
        name = tokenName;                                   // Set the name for display purposes
        symbol = tokenSymbol;                               // Set the symbol for display purposes
    }

    /**
     * Internal transfer, only can be called by this contract
     */
    function _transfer(address _from, address _to, uint _value) internal {
        // Prevent transfer to 0x0 address. Use burn() instead
        require(_to != 0x0);
        // Check if the sender has enough
        require(balanceOf[_from] >= _value);
        // Check for overflows
        require(balanceOf[_to] + _value > balanceOf[_to]);
        // Save this for an assertion in the future
        uint previousBalances = balanceOf[_from] + balanceOf[_to];
        // Subtract from the sender
        balanceOf[_from] -= _value;
        // Add the same to the recipient
        balanceOf[_to] += _value;
        Transfer(_from, _to, _value);
        // Asserts are used to use static analysis to find bugs in your code. They should never fail
        assert(balanceOf[_from] + balanceOf[_to] == previousBalances);
    }

    /**
     * Transfer tokens
     *
     * Send `_value` tokens to `_to` from your account
     *
     * @param _to The address of the recipient
     * @param _value the amount to send
     */
    function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public {
        _transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);
    }

    /**
     * Transfer tokens from other address
     *
     * Send `_value` tokens to `_to` in behalf of `_from`
     *
     * @param _from The address of the sender
     * @param _to The address of the recipient
     * @param _value the amount to send
     */
    function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
        require(_value <= allowance[_from][msg.sender]);     // Check allowance
        allowance[_from][msg.sender] -= _value;
        _transfer(_from, _to, _value);
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Set allowance for other address
     *
     * Allows `_spender` to spend no more than `_value` tokens in your behalf
     *
     * @param _spender The address authorized to spend
     * @param _value the max amount they can spend
     */
    function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) public
        returns (bool success) {
        allowance[msg.sender][_spender] = _value;
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Set allowance for other address and notify
     *
     * Allows `_spender` to spend no more than `_value` tokens in your behalf, and then ping the contract about it
     *
     * @param _spender The address authorized to spend
     * @param _value the max amount they can spend
     * @param _extraData some extra information to send to the approved contract
     */
    function approveAndCall(address _spender, uint256 _value, bytes _extraData)
        public
        returns (bool success) {
        tokenRecipient spender = tokenRecipient(_spender);
        if (approve(_spender, _value)) {
            spender.receiveApproval(msg.sender, _value, this, _extraData);
            return true;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Destroy tokens
     *
     * Remove `_value` tokens from the system irreversibly
     *
     * @param _value the amount of money to burn
     */
    function burn(uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
        require(balanceOf[msg.sender] >= _value);   // Check if the sender has enough
        balanceOf[msg.sender] -= _value;            // Subtract from the sender
        totalSupply -= _value;                      // Updates totalSupply
        Burn(msg.sender, _value);
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Destroy tokens from other account
     *
     * Remove `_value` tokens from the system irreversibly on behalf of `_from`.
     *
     * @param _from the address of the sender
     * @param _value the amount of money to burn
     */
    function burnFrom(address _from, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
        require(balanceOf[_from] >= _value);                // Check if the targeted balance is enough
        require(_value <= allowance[_from][msg.sender]);    // Check allowance
        balanceOf[_from] -= _value;                         // Subtract from the targeted balance
        allowance[_from][msg.sender] -= _value;             // Subtract from the sender's allowance
        totalSupply -= _value;                              // Update totalSupply
        Burn(_from, _value);
        return true;
    }
}

/******************************************/
/*       ADVANCED TOKEN STARTS HERE       */
/******************************************/

contract MyAdvancedToken is owned, TokenERC20 {

    uint256 public sellPrice;
    uint256 public buyPrice;

    mapping (address => bool) public frozenAccount;

    /* This generates a public event on the blockchain that will notify clients */
    event FrozenFunds(address target, bool frozen);

    /* Initializes contract with initial supply tokens to the creator of the contract */
    function MyAdvancedToken(
        uint256 initialSupply,
        string tokenName,
        string tokenSymbol
    ) TokenERC20(initialSupply, tokenName, tokenSymbol) public {}

    /* Internal transfer, only can be called by this contract */
    function _transfer(address _from, address _to, uint _value) internal {
        require (_to != 0x0);                               // Prevent transfer to 0x0 address. Use burn() instead
        require (balanceOf[_from] >= _value);               // Check if the sender has enough
        require (balanceOf[_to] + _value > balanceOf[_to]); // Check for overflows
        require(!frozenAccount[_from]);                     // Check if sender is frozen
        require(!frozenAccount[_to]);                       // Check if recipient is frozen
        balanceOf[_from] -= _value;                         // Subtract from the sender
        balanceOf[_to] += _value;                           // Add the same to the recipient
        Transfer(_from, _to, _value);
    }

    /// @notice Create `mintedAmount` tokens and send it to `target`
    /// @param target Address to receive the tokens
    /// @param mintedAmount the amount of tokens it will receive
    function mintToken(address target, uint256 mintedAmount) onlyOwner public {
        balanceOf[target] += mintedAmount;
        totalSupply += mintedAmount;
        Transfer(0, this, mintedAmount);
        Transfer(this, target, mintedAmount);
    }

    /// @notice `freeze? Prevent | Allow` `target` from sending & receiving tokens
    /// @param target Address to be frozen
    /// @param freeze either to freeze it or not
    function freezeAccount(address target, bool freeze) onlyOwner public {
        frozenAccount[target] = freeze;
        FrozenFunds(target, freeze);
    }

    /// @notice Allow users to buy tokens for `newBuyPrice` eth and sell tokens for `newSellPrice` eth
    /// @param newSellPrice Price the users can sell to the contract
    /// @param newBuyPrice Price users can buy from the contract
    function setPrices(uint256 newSellPrice, uint256 newBuyPrice) onlyOwner public {
        sellPrice = newSellPrice;
        buyPrice = newBuyPrice;
    }

    /// @notice Buy tokens from contract by sending ether
    function buy() payable public {
        uint amount = msg.value / buyPrice;               // calculates the amount
        _transfer(this, msg.sender, amount);              // makes the transfers
    }

    /// @notice Sell `amount` tokens to contract
    /// @param amount amount of tokens to be sold
    function sell(uint256 amount) public {
        require(this.balance >= amount * sellPrice);      // checks if the contract has enough ether to buy
        _transfer(msg.sender, this, amount);              // makes the transfers
        msg.sender.transfer(amount * sellPrice);          // sends ether to the seller. It's important to do this last to avoid recursion attacks
    }
}
```

And the code for the crowdsale

```
 pragma solidity ^0.4.16;

interface token {
    function transfer(address receiver, uint amount) public ;
}

contract Crowdsale {
    address public beneficiary;
    uint public fundingGoal;
    uint public amountRaised;
    uint public deadline;
    uint public price;
    token public tokenReward;
    mapping(address => uint256) public balanceOf;
    bool fundingGoalReached = false;
    bool crowdsaleClosed = false;

    event GoalReached(address recipient, uint totalAmountRaised);
    event FundTransfer(address backer, uint amount, bool isContribution);

    /**
     * Constrctor function
     *
     * Setup the owner
     */
    function Crowdsale (
        address ifSuccessfulSendTo,
        uint fundingGoalInEthers,
        uint durationInMinutes,
        uint etherCostOfEachToken,
        address addressOfTokenUsedAsReward
    ) public {
        beneficiary = ifSuccessfulSendTo;
        fundingGoal = fundingGoalInEthers * 1 ether;
        deadline = now + durationInMinutes * 1 minutes;
        price = etherCostOfEachToken * 1 ether;
        tokenReward = token(addressOfTokenUsedAsReward) ;
    }

    /**
     * Fallback function
     *
     * The function without name is the default function that is called whenever anyone sends funds to a contract
     */
    function  () payable public  { 

        require(!crowdsaleClosed);
        uint amount = msg.value;
        balanceOf[msg.sender] += amount;
        amountRaised += amount;
        tokenReward.transfer(msg.sender, amount / price);
        FundTransfer(msg.sender, amount, true); 

     }

    modifier afterDeadline() { if (now >= deadline) _; }

    /**
     * Check if goal was reached
     *
     * Checks if the goal or time limit has been reached and ends the campaign
     */
    function checkGoalReached() afterDeadline public {
        if (amountRaised >= fundingGoal){
            fundingGoalReached = true;
            GoalReached(beneficiary, amountRaised);
        }
        crowdsaleClosed = true;
    }


    /**
     * Withdraw the funds
     *
     * Checks to see if goal or time limit has been reached, and if so, and the funding goal was reached,
     * sends the entire amount to the beneficiary. If goal was not reached, each contributor can withdraw
     * the amount they contributed.
     */
    function safeWithdrawal() afterDeadline  public {
        if (!fundingGoalReached) {
            uint amount = balanceOf[msg.sender];
            balanceOf[msg.sender] = 0;
            if (amount > 0) {
                if (msg.sender.send(amount)) {
                    FundTransfer(msg.sender, amount, false);
                } else {
                    balanceOf[msg.sender] = amount;
                }
            }
        }

        if (fundingGoalReached && beneficiary == msg.sender) {
            if (beneficiary.send(amountRaised)) {
                FundTransfer(beneficiary, amountRaised, false);
            } else {
                //If we fail to send the funds to beneficiary, unlock funders balance
                fundingGoalReached = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I used Mist with the blockchain updated (synced?).

Appreciate any help, thanks!